# Rsync behavior with changed files

Tags: files, rsync

When after running rsync for the first time a file is changed on the source, when you next run rsync on the same filesystem does it copy the whole file from the source again or just the changes to the file?

Answer (score 5):

Rysnc has an almost insane number of options, so the answer is "it depends".

Generally rsync will only copy changed "blocks" from a file--from the manpage:

> It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination.

If you want only "whole files": 
     -W, --whole-file

Also look at the --inplace flag.

Rsync doesn't have a "man page", it's got a "man book" that is pretty dense.

Answer (score -1):

`rsync` is a very good tool for daily backups, and daily file transfer. With `rsync` you can copy files and their attributes, like permission or owner.

```bsh
rsync -v -a foo/ bar/
```

This is a simple syntax